# How to read the filenames from an input directory that starts with the prefixes in a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the current function to read file from a local directory when the filename starts with certain prefix.
Now I have second use case where multiple prefixes are in a list like['prefix1', 'prefix2'] . How can I modify the code below for finding multiple filenames from the local directory where filename start with prefixes in the list?
If I use the current function than it gives error as now the prefix is not string but list.

```
if dev:
    print('Reading files from dowloaded data')
    for filename in os.listdir('Data\Input_data'):
        if prefix in filename:
            print ('using downloaded file',filename)
            df_file = os.path.join ('Data\Input_data',filename)
            if df == None:
                df = df_file
            else:
                df.append(df_file)
```

Comment: why dont u just use `glob` package. If you do something like `my_files = glob.glob("Data\Input_Data\myprefix*")` you get list of all files.

Comment: If you want to input list, you can use list comprehension  like `myfiles = [glob.glob(pattern) for pattern in my_patterns][0]` where `mypattern` is list of patterns of prefix like `['*.py', '*.csv']`

Comment: This does not return the files from the directory that start with the prefixes in list .

Comment: Instead of **if prefix in filename**, the logic will be inversed like this: **if (some part of the filename) in prefix**

Comment: @KishuP, Are all perifix has the same size?

Comment: you obviously have to take your own list `['prefix1', 'prefix2']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is about this line:

`if prefix in filename`

The logic will be inversed like this:

`if (some part of the filename) in prefix`  , where `prefix` is a list like['prefix1', 'prefix2',..]

You can solve this using `startswith` method and a `tuple` of the prefixes list.

For example:

```
prefix_list=['prefix1', 'prefix2','prefix3', 'prefix3']
filename="prefix30000"
print(filename.startswith(tuple(prefix_list)))
#True
```

Then you can modify your code like this:

```
if dev:
    print('Reading files from dowloaded data')
    for filename in os.listdir('Data\Input_data'):
        if filename.startswith(tuple(prefix)): # << Updated line
            print ('using downloaded file',filename)
            df_file = os.path.join ('Data\Input_data',filename)
            if df == None:
                df = df_file
            else:
                df.append(df_file)
```